# UILabel in UITableViewCell using Autolayout sizes correctly but only wraps on rotation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I use the programatic constraints from the WWDC '14 talk on `UITableView`s so that my app can support dynamic text and adjust the height of my table view cells automatically. But the wrapping only shows up if I rotate the device to landscape and back. The first picture below shows this: the initial view is wrong. The second shows what I expected, but I only get the correct behaviour after I rotate to landscape and back.

Notice that the size of the cells is correct: the auto layout system has figured out that I need two lines of space, and yet the text did not wrap.

I tried setting the line break mode - it sort of works (breaks at a character or word depending on the mode, but I don't see the rest of the string until I rotate).

The constraints for the label are identical to the ones in the WWDC '14 talk. I get not auto layout complaints. I have set number of rows of the `UILabel` to 0, set the row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and set the estimated row height.

Has anyone seen this before and fixed it? What have I done wrong?

[image]

Second picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with `UICollectionViewCell`s. I wanted a multiline label that would grow as needed. What you're doing should probably work, especially since that's all that's shown in the WWDC video.

I ended up calling `[label setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` within `layoutSubviews` prior to calling `[super layoutSubviews]`.

With this approach, I do *not* explicitly set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to 0. That actually caused an issue for me. The default *is* 0, so you can just leave it.

I had some notes on on other approaches that also worked:

- Save label text, set label.text to nil, then set text back to
  original prior to [super layoutSubviews].
- After [super layoutSubviews], set preferredMaxLayoutWidth to current label width (constraints have been applied, just want to sync the layout width value with reality, which then triggers some additional work)

If you don't have a custom cell class to do this in, you might try calling `[label setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` from the table view delegate/data source methods such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

In a subclass of UILabel I placed this code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
}
```